# Haw to save the new result which are extracting from csv file in python?

Tags: python

I have the (M.csv) file contain many columns.
I extract 2 columns from the (M.CSV) file by using DictReader, Now I want to save these 2 columns in New CSV file. I use data.to_csv(.....) but not working.

this is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
with open('M.csv', newline='') as f:
 data = csv.DictReader(f)
 print("I_CaIIHK",",", 'Swm')
 print("---------------------------------")
 for row in data:
    print(row['I_CaIIHK_err'],"," ,row['Swm'])
    
data.to_csv('New.csv',index=False)
```

the code is run and I got the 2 columns but cannot saving in new csv file.

And this is the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DictReader' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYZYS.jpg)

Comment: `data` isn't a pandas dataframe, so you can't use the `to_csv` method on it. For this use case, I don't think you really even need to open the file and read it with `csv.DictReader`, you can probably just use `pd.from_csv` to extract whatever you need from the file. That being said, it's unclear what you're trying to do, especially on the last line. Maybe instead of printing the data read from `M.csv` save it to a variable?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to call the [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method on a [csv.DictReader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) object (which is not a DataFrame).
You should be able to read the CSV file into a `DataFrame` with the [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) function, specifying only the columns you want with the `usecols` argument, then save the data with the [pandas.DataFrame.to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method.

Then you don't need the `csv` library at all :).

Something like:

```
import pandas as pd

COLUMNS_TO_USE = ["I_CaIIHK_err", "Swm"]
PATH_TO_FILE = "./M.csv"
OUTPUT_FILE = "New.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(filepath=PATH_TO_FILE, usecols=COLUMNS_TO_USE)
df.to_csv(path_or_buf=OUTPUT_FILE)
```